# Issues with bookmarks (showing twice in PDF)

Tags: hyperref, pdf, bookmarks

I am using Overleaf for LaTeX editing and am creating a rendition of a tabletop miniature wargaming rulebook (Grimdark Future, if you know it). I always wanted to learn the LaTeX typesetting and this (combined with my translation hobby) offered me the way to go forward. The reason is that potential rulebook translators can just replace the relevant text in the source file and render a localized PDF with (relative) ease, compared to the necessary tinkering with graphical layout in InDesign, Scribus, or Word for that matter).

I am basically done with laying out the PDF already, but have issues with bookmarks in the final PDF.

I am using secions/subsections and have disabled their numbering with "\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}" - but this might cause issues with the in-built hyperref bookmarks inserted into the PDF, as far as I could find on teh interwebz.

1. How can I correct this, so that the bookmarks have the proper section/subsection structure in the PDF?
2. In my code I also used "\pdfbookmark[2]{Introduction}{Introduction}" to manually create a structure and this would be fine, but these are in the end showing as duplicates beside/inbetween of the regular hyperref bookmarks in the PDF.
3. Or should I use the "bookmark" package and "\bookmark" instead of the native hyperref's \pdfbookmark? If so, how? When checking the documentation for the bookmark package I did not find a consistent and easily readable example that I could reproduce.

I searched internet for answers, but they were either only tangential, or the solutions did not work (mainly setting various options for the hyperref package).

The whole Github code repo is in here (without pictures so far):
[Grimdark Future rules in TeX](https://github.com/joeyeti/Grimdark-Future-rules-in-TeX)

Comment: I will not debug code in an external github. Provide a small but complete example showing your problems here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  A whole Github repo is a lot for us to look through.  Could you boil what you're doing down to a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497) that shows how you're using `\section` and `\pdfbookmark`?